# Exporting JavaFX2 to Android

Tags: java, android, javafx-2

i have a stupid question. Its possible to export JavaFX2 to Android. I have some Object in my JavaFX2 world and i would like to use this for a simple Android Application. I already exported some classes into the Android e.g. SimpleStringProperty, but with some i getting always an exception  **org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;**

I will be very happy for every ideas... big thanks!!

Update: is the amount of classes limited ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slf4j is a logging wrapper which is unrelated to JavaFX.

Consult the [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) documentation and the documentation for whatever logging framework you are wrapping in slf4j to help resolve your problem.  If you include in your question the full stack trace for the error you receive you might be able to get more assistance.

There is currently (as of JavaFX 2.0) no public port of JavaFX to Android and Android is not a supported platform for JavaFX.  For the majority of the JavaFX functionality, I'd advise waiting until when (and if) Oracle release an Android build for JavaFX before trying to use it on Android.

There is a reasonable chance that the property and binding framework from JavaFX (javafx.beans.* packages) would work on Android as that code was designed to work independently of the rest of JavaFX.  The property and binding part of JavaFX is currently not open source, though a lot of the rest of the JavaFX source code is.  The framework was developed to run on top of JavaSE and not Android, so some Android specific source code changes may be required to allow the JavaFX property and binding framework to run on Android.  Also, before doing something like that I would advise checking the [JavaFX license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) (which is the same as the Java SE license).